# Taxation Law when paid in Chickens

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

If I were to be paid for my work with chickens instead of money and several of the chickens died within a short period of the time of receipt, would they still be subject to the standard rules of UK Income Tax?

Comment: you should wait to accept an answer as a better answer may not be written simply because an OK answer exists.

Comment: that and if you are being paid in chickens be sure to get the payer to get a quant to mark them to market for you.

Comment: How many chickens are we talking about here?

Answer (score 6):

I am not a tax accountant and the caveats about taking tax advice from random people on the internet stand. I have, however, had partial payment as in specie benefit in the past so have a good idea of how this is taxed. The chickens are taxed as in specie benefits (supposing you classify the chickens as beneficial) at the same rate as any other payment. That the chickens died soon after has no effect unless it was for a reason that meant that their value was lower at the time that you received them than was accounted for for tax reasons. If their value at that time was less than reported you can write down the value and receive a tax rebate for the amount of tax on that write down.